# Encrypt multiple hard drives in Windows, each required for boot

Tags: windows, hard-drive, encryption, bitlocker, disk-encryption

I have two drives, a small SSD (boot device) and a much larger drive for data. I want to encrypt these drives, but the problem is that *both* of them need to be available at boot time. I have many programs installed to the data drive that run at boot in addition to those on the SSD. Each drive has only one partition, other than the few system partitions on the boot SSD.

I don't know if VeraCrypt or Bitlocker would be preferred for this (or preferred in general), but I'm on Windows 10 Education x64 so I have full access to all BitLocker features.

How can I encrypt multiple hard drives so that all will be decrypted at boot?

Comment: The system drive will be mounted once the passphrase is provided in either case.  The second volume will be provided once the passphrase is provided when the user logs into their account ( or with Bitlocker automatically if you choose to save the passphrase).  Automatically mounting either volume without any user prompt would defeat the purpose of the encryption.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm sorry, I don't mean I don't want a password. I want to be prompted for one or both passwords so they're both mounted at the same time, instead of manually mounting the data drive after boot.

Comment: There isn't FDE software that does what you want.  The system drive in all current existing solutions will be mounted, then the OS will boot, then you can mount any additional drives.

Comment: @Ramhound Understandable. You can post that as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Both TrueCrypt and VeraCrypt support mounting of non-system volumes (system favorites) pre-login in addition to the system volume / disk if those other volumes use the same password as the system volume / disk.